# Call a method from Activitys

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'd like to call a method which is declared in an Activity. This method is declared in more Activitys but has different work to do. I also have a simple java class and I'd like to call this method from the current activity.
So I need a way to call this method from the current activity and not from a certain activity. Is there any way to do it? I have already tried to do it with giving the context and the activity of the current Activity to the class but I don't what to do wit it. I thougt something like this:

Actitvity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Todo t = new Todo(this,this);
}

public void example(){
    //here do something
}
```

Java class:

```
public class Todo {

Context context;
Activity activity;

public Todo(Context context,Activity activity){
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
}
public void eventhere(){
    activity.example();
}
}
```

Comment: you need an interface for that.

Comment: or create a baseActivity use it as a Parent activity for each of your other activities. Declare your method in base and define it in child activities

Comment: This is really more of a Java question than an Android question.  It is advisable that you have a basic understanding of the Java programming language before attempting to create an Android application.  Just some friendly advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping that your example is over-simplified, since your Activity is creating an instance of the Todo class, just so that it can invoke a method in it that invokes a method back in the Activity class.

This would be exactly equivalent to the Activity just invoking it's own method, and leaving the Todo object out entirely.

So, perhaps if you explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to do, we could point you in the right direction.

However, I'll take a guess. It looks like you may be trying to implement the Command Pattern, with your Todo objects acting as the Commands.
Perhaps you want to create these commands somewhere else, and execute them at a later time?

I think that an interesting way to do this would be to use a message bus.
For instance, different sub-classes of Todo could, when 'executed', place a different 'message' object on the bus. The Activities could then subscribe to the bus, and respond to the bus messages by invoking their appropriate methods.

This pattern would keep things loosely-coupled. Todo objects would not need knowledge of specific Activity subclasses, and the Activities would not need to know about the Todo objects. The only things in common would be the Bus and the messages that are put on the Bus.